# Посчитать % при разных числах

Tags: c#, математика

Есть такой код:

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(s);
double onePercent = value / 100;
value = value + onePercent * 10;
return value.ToString();
```

`value = value + 10%`

Как сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от числа, добавлялся уникальный `%`?

Например:

> 200 + 30%
>   600 + 25%
>   1000 + 20%
>   1400 + 15%
>   2000 + 10%

То есть хотелось бы, чтобы результатом исполнения было не `value = value + 10%`, a `value = value + n%`!

`n` = процент, в зависимости от числа `value` (пример выше)

Comment: как n зависит от x?

Answer (score 3):

Пожалуйста, *в зависимости от суммы числа*:

```
if (value == 200)
  value = value + onePercent * 30;
else if (value == 600)
  value = value + onePercent * 25;
else if (value == 1000)
  value = value + onePercent * 20;
else if (value == 1400)
  value = value + onePercent * 15;
else if (value == 2000)
  value = value + onePercent * 10;
```

Comment: Решение верное, только равенство надо заменить. На `<=`, вероятно.

Comment: Я уже хотел вывести формулу, но последней строчкой он эту формулу зарезал. Боюсь думать, что там между перечисленными ценами.

Comment: Мне кажется, что процент должен зависеть от интервала. В общем случае нужно иметь список (массив) интервалов. Любители оптимизации могут попробовать построить сбалансированное двоичное дерево.

Comment: Думаю, Вы правы и все определяется формулой, зависящей от интервалов. Представил свою телепатическую догадку в ответе)

Comment: @avp а для чего нужен массив интервалов, если есть определенная периодичность (которая вроде бы наблюдается в данном вопросе)?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, в данном конкретном случае, конечно, можно написать формулу. В общем случае без массива (списка) не обойтись

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос не слишком ясен: Вы не описали, как зависит процент от значения `value`!
Пришлось догадываться и выводить формулу на основе Ваших примеров самостоятельно)
Функция получилась следующей:

```
// Получим число + некий процент от него
private static double GetValue(double Value) => 
    Value < 0 ? 
        // Число не может быть меньше нуля (у Вас это некая сумма, как я понял)
        throw new ArgumentException() : 
        // Если число меньше порога, когда процент начинает становиться отрицательным
        Value < 2800 ? 
            // Добавить процент
            (Value + (30.0 - (int)(Value - 1) / 400 * 5) / 100 * Value) : 
            // Вернуть число без начислений
            Value;
```

Пример работы:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetValue(200));  // 260  == 200  + 200  * 0.30
Console.WriteLine(GetValue(600));  // 750  == 600  + 600  * 0.25
Console.WriteLine(GetValue(1000)); // 1200 == 1000 + 1000 * 0.20  
Console.WriteLine(GetValue(1400)); // 1610 == 1400 + 1400 * 0.15
Console.WriteLine(GetValue(2000)); // 2200 == 2000 + 2000 * 0.10
```

---

Надеюсь, мое решение помогло Вам, если же нет - детальнее опишите проблему!